# Autocomplete with source read from JSON Array stored in Label not working

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

I am using JQuery Autocomplete, and want to populate it from a JSON Array read from a hidden Label.

This code:

```
string[] tags = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Lychee", "Pear", "Lemon" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tags);
lblJson.Text = json;
```

produces this result:

[image]

I am trying to then populate the autocomplete source with this array like this:

```
var availableTags = $("#lblJson").text();
$("#tbTag").autocomplete({
  source:availableTags
});
```

but my autocomplete doesn't, err, autocomplete.

However, if I copy the JSON array directly into the Javascript code it works fine:

```
var availableTags = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Lychee", "Pear", "Lemon"];
$("#tbTag").autocomplete({
  source:availableTags
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var availableTags = $("#lblJson").text();
> ```

The `availableTags` you got here is not an array, but rather a string that contains a json array.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use this to parse it:

```
var json = $("#lblJson").text();
var availableTags = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: Legend! I've been banging my head on this one! :-)